# Reassigning values in an array of objects in Julia

Tags: julia

I am a new learner of Julia language. I have defined an array of objects as follows:

```
type a
     b :: Int
     c :: Int
end
d = Array{a}(3)
```

This returns me a 3-element Array{a,1} with garbage values. I want to assign values into it. I have written the following code, but it is not working.

```
for i = 1:3
    d[i].b = i
    d[i].c = i^2
end
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize your `a` you must call a constructor. Also, you can use [comprehension](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/arrays/#Comprehensions-1) to construct the array:

```
type a
     b :: Int
     c :: Int
end

d=[a(i,i^2) for i in 1:3]
```

which gives

```
3-element Array{a,1}:
 a(1, 1)
 a(2, 4)
 a(3, 9)
```

---

Also note that `type` is deprecated, it is better to declare your composite types as:

```
struct Foo ... end
```

or

```
mutable struct Foo ... end
```

See official doc: [Composite types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Composite-Types-1) and [Mutable composite types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Mutable-Composite-Types-1)

---

Update (your comment): yes you can use any function...

```
function f() # can also use any argument 
         # long computation... for demo random number
         b=rand(Int8)
         c=rand(Int8)
         return a(b,c)
       end
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> d=[f() for i in 1:3]
3-element Array{a,1}:
 a(80, 104)
 a(98, -62)
 a(-37, 17)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For a demo purpose, we consider a simple example. Actually, we require to do a longer operation. On a note, is it possible to do the same operation using a function which returns an object of type a?